# How enable IR leds on webcam using linux command

Tags: linux, webcam

I have this webcam iSlim321R USB\VID_0458&PID_705F&REV_0100&MI_00
It has 4 working IR leds. I can enable them by windows(obs)
But how enable it by linux command?
[same problem, I tried this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/how-to-control-leds-from-usb-webcam-4175443370/)
is it possible to sniff usb traffic from obs and reapply this data using linux?
[obs example](https://youtu.be/n81y22D4Xow)

sorry for the quality. I do not have standard definition and YouTube cuts it off

Comment: Knowing what option you use to enable it in OBS might help people find a similar option elsewhere...

Comment: @A.B https://is.gd/ZXtjbB clear. but in v4l and input there is a mention of islim and leds. but permission denied

Comment: So looking at that video you are looking for a "focus" option https://stackoverflow.com/a/56028295/278545

Comment: @Mokubai https://is.gd/L5IJUq . with absolute same trouble

Comment: can you run `v4l2-ctl -d 0 --list-ctrls` and paste the output in your question?

Comment: @Mokubai https://is.gd/DrlWs5 this work tnx

Comment: Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install v4l-utils
```

**v4l2-ctl -d 0 -c focus_absolute=1**

Thank you @Mokubai